# How to overcome burn problems or buy installation disk?

Tags: system-installation, iso, burning

I have tried and tried to download and burn Ubuntu 13.04 without success. The first time took 18 hours. Where and from whom can I purchase a installation disc in Atlanta, Georgia.

Comment: Where are you downloading from?  and How are you burning?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can buy CDs or DVDs of the distributions in bulk: http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Or here: [http://www.amazon.com/Ubuntu-4-discs-Installation-Reference-Ed-2013/dp/B0047B0U1C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047B0U1C)